# Do PhoneGap / Cordova javascript calls require CordovaWebView or DroidGap?

Tags: android, cordova

It is possible to call a PhoneGap javascript function from a plain `WebView`?

The following code does not seem to be enough to allow my html page to call PhoneGap functions. My function calls fail when my app uses `WebView`, but succeed when my app uses an activity that `extends DroidGap`.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that DroidGap initializes a lot of the bridging functionality that is required to use the PG features, otherwise it would be very magical if it was possible to use them with only JS.

Comment: No, but why would you not want to extend DroidGap? It contains the code to bridge the js and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call PhoneGap functions from a normal web view.  The code you are showing is from the initial project template for a new PhoneGap project - the initialize function setups up event handlers that get triggered by the ondeviceready event. The ondeviceready event is specific to PhoneGap applications.  It does not exist within a normal web view.  PhoneGap API functions will not work - you can only use the JavaScript APIs that are supported by the system web browser.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by: you can only use the JavaScript APIs that are supported by the system web browser

Comment: PhoneGap leverages the system web browser for UI rendering, and exposes additional JavaScript-based APIs for interacting with the native operating system layer.   In "normal" system web views, you can only use JavaScript APIs that are supported by the web view by default - the PhoneGap APIs will not be available.   Things like local file system access, or the ability to search contacts on a device will not work.  However, normal browser-based JS APIs will work, like accessing the DOM, applying CSS styles, geolocation (where supported), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to call a javascript function from a plain WebView. For that you need to write your own avaScriptInterface. Follow the link below for a sample

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

But, I am sure you cannot use the PhoneGap features using this method.  If, you are looking for phonegap based solution, then you must extend your activity from DroidGap activity.

Comment: Technically, you do not need to extend from `DroidGap`, but rather embed a `CordovaWebView`. That being said, at the time of this writing, the separation of `CordovaWebView` from `DroidGap` is... rather rough. So, in practice, using `DroidGap` is probably a better solution. FWIW, here is an app I put together recently that inherits from `DroidGap`: https://github.com/commonsguy/gapPlayer